# I have a problem with a variable in AppDelegate

Tags: swift, sinch

I have an error in my code when trying to return a variable that is in the App delegate to a viewController, it returns a null value and therefore does not assign the delegate

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var client: SINClient!
.
.
.
}
```

---

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, SINCallClientDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var destination: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    func client() -> SINClient? {
        return (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).client
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.client()?.call().delegate = self
    }

    @IBAction func actionCall(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if destination.text != "" && self.client()!.isStarted() {
            weak var call = client()!.call().callUserVideo(withId: destination.text)
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "callView", sender: call)
        }
    }

    func client(_ client: SINCallClient?, didReceiveIncomingCall call: SINCall?) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "callView", sender: call)
    }
}
```

> Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Show the code where you assign a value to the `client` property of your AppDelegate.

Comment: Most likely `awakeFormNib` in `ViewController` is called much sooner than the code which sets `client` in AppDelegate.

Comment: Did u initialize the `client` in AppDelegate?